# Can't Delete Directory

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code in order to try to clear the Java cache:

```
Dim TheFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache"
'check if the folder exists  
If IO.Directory.Exists(TheFolderPath) Then
    'delete the folder and all its contents  
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(TheFolderPath, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
End If
```

However, when I run the tool to test its functionality the tool does not delete the folder. Can you please assist?

Comment: I do. I personally am an ADMIN on the system; however, I am also trying to design this for those who are not admins.

Comment: doesnt `%username%` need to be substituted with a real username first?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I was trying to make it happen for whoevers user ID was running it.

Comment: Example: If I run it and my username is JDoe1 it would delete it from JDoe1  but if you run it and it's JDoe2 it would delete it for JDoe2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634054/accessing-appdata-with-vb-net

Comment: CHANGE %username% to %userprofile%  !!! %username% is not a valid folder in Windows

Comment: I don't think VB.NET even reads the Environment Variables. So using that in your path's will probably not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your path string contains an environment variable (`%username%`) which you must [expand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first:

```
Dim TheFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache"
TheFolderPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(TheFolderPath)
```

`%username%` is a placeholder for the name of the currently logged-in user (Windows automatically creates an environment variable `username` with the username at login). However, inside a string the placeholder is just a literal string `%username%`. To actually have it substituted with the value of the environment variable you need to use the function mentioned above.

Comment: @Chris06991 : He just gave you some code. Just put it in place of the one you have now. VB.NET doesn't read Environment variables such as `%username%`, so to get your path to work properly you must use the `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `Environment.UserName` property, which gets the logged in user's user name, and then construct a path with that and `IO.Path.Combine()`.

```
Dim TheFolderPath As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users", Environment.UserName, "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache")
```